# When using function pointer, what does the & mark do

Tags: c++

When using function pointers, sometime we add & before the function name, sometime we don't. What's the difference between these two?

```
void say_hi(void) {
    cout << "Hi.." << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void (*func)(void) = &say_hi;
    void (*func1)(void) = say_hi;
    void (*func2)(void) = *say_hi;
    void (*func3)(void) = **say_hi;
    func();
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code:

```
Hi..
Hi.. 
Hi..
Hi..
```

Comment: `say_hi` is equivalent to `&say_hi` because it implicitly decays into a function pointer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 in this context, not everywhere. :)

Comment: I've edited the question a little to show that adding an arbitrary number of `*` dereferencing at the front also makes no difference.  I hope nobody feels I've changed the meaning of the question too much.

Comment: Check the accepted answer of that dupe, its much more verbose and even explains your edited part. (dereferenced function pointers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The & is "still" just the address of. Functions however enjoy decaying into function pointers similar to arrays decaying into "plain" pointers.